# Is there a thesaurus or Wikipedia plugin for Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, plugins

I found a few dictionary plugins for Visual Studio, but I couldn't find any thesaurus plugins.  Ideally I would right click on a word or part of a variable name and it could give a few suggestions for alternatives.  Another idea is a Wikipedia plugin that offers to look up phrases on Wikipedia.
I haven't seen either of these, do you know of any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've recently published a Visual Studio extension called 'Synonyms' that does exactly what you ask. Right-click on a word (can be part of a variable/member name) and expand the 'Synonyms' sub-menu to see alternatives. Select an alternative from the menu to have it replace the word you right-clicked on.

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4a5c5172-559f-415c-9142-8e0370d3c0b0

[image: 'Synonyms' Visual Studio Extension]